# How to retain the value of a variable inside for loop in shell script

Tags: shell

Below is my shell script code:

```
#!/bin/bash
first=0

my_for_loop()
{

 first="$1";
 if [ $first -eq 0 ]
 then
   return 1;
 elif [ $first -eq 1 ]
then
   return 0;
 fi
}

while read line; do
for word in $line; do
    echo "word = '$word'"; ( echo "$word" | grep -Eq  "\([0-9]+\)" ) && ( word="${word%\)}"; word="`echo ${word} | cut -d'(' -f 2`"; echo "no = $word";
my_for_loop "$first"; first="$?"; echo "foo = $first")
done
echo "first value is $first" )
done
```

Basically I'm trying to read the words from the input and checking whether it is of the form "([0-9]+)" {e.g. (120) } if so, extracting the numerals i.e 120

The problem arises when I'm trying to set the variable "first" to 1 on the odd no of occurence of the pattern, and to 0 on eventh occurence

I tried Process Substitution, but not working porperly.

Can you help me with setting the boolean value inside the for loop such that it retains the value during next iteration also?

Comment: You set the variable `word` in a child process, so there are several independent copies of a variable named `word` floating around. I don't quite see, why you want to do the  `word="${word%\)}"` part in a sub-process. You could do it in the main process (by using curly braces instead of round one). BTW, while it looks (and often is) clever to use `&&` to control execution flow, a good old `if - then - else - fi` is sometimes more flexible and more readable; I think this is the case here.

Comment: [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) is on-point.

Comment: In general, don't use parentheses if all you want is grouping -- they create a completely new and independent process. Braces are your friend.

Comment: ...there are a bunch of other bugs in this code, many of them still present in the updated version in @WalterA's answer; consider running contents through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: Being a beginner to Shell script struggled a lot, but the methods you suggested are cool and helped alot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid subprocesses. Is this want you want:

```
i=0
while read line ; do
   cutted=$(sed 's/^(\([0-9]*\))$/\1/'  <<< $line)
   if [ "${line}" != "${cutted}" ]; then
      (( i = !i))
      echo "First=$i and ${cutted}"
   fi
done
```

and use another loop when you cut things in words

```
i=0
while read line ; do
   for word in $line; do
      echo "${word}"
      cutted=$(sed 's/^(\([0-9]*\))$/\1/'  <<< ${word})
      if [ "${word}" != "${cutted}" ]; then
         (( i = !i))
         echo "First=$i and ${cutted}"
      fi
   done
done
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked fine. Thanks a lot!!